# Cordova InAppBrowser clear search history

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I'm creating an app where you can open google to find a solution on an answer:

```
 ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://google.nl/', '_blank', 'clearsessioncache=yes, clearcache=yes');
```

Despite I send the properties clearsessioncache=yes, clearcache=yes and I'm not logged in on Google it keeps showing previous search results when I enter the search box.

Can someone explain why the history keeps showing in the 'suggested' sites? And if there is any way to prevent this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer myself. Hope it helps someone else with the same problem:

Google search history is stored in localStorage. So clearing localStorage before showing the InAppBrowser solves the problem:

```
this.ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://www.google.nl/', '_blank', 'clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes,closebuttoncaption=Terug,closebuttoncolor=#4286f4,hideurlbar=yes,hidden=yes');
this.ref.addEventListener('loadstop', () => {
    var init = false
    this.ref.addEventListener('loadstop', () => {
        if (!init) {
            // clear localStorage to clear Google search history
            this.ref.executeScript({
                code: `
        (function() { 
            localStorage.clear();
            return true;
         })()` }, _ => {
                    // cache is cleared. Now we can show the browser.
                    this.ref.show();
                    init = true;
                });
        }
    });
});
```